# Overload NSDictionary getter in swift extension

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I want to use mu custom enum as key for my dictionary. So far I did this:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    enum DBKeys : String {
        case Key1 = "Key1", Key2 = "key2", Key3 = "key3"
    }


    func valueForKey(key : DBKeys) -> AnyObject? {
        return self[key.rawValue]
    }
}
```

This is allow my to do something like this:

```
    let dic = NSDictionary()
    dic.valueForKey(.Key1)
```

But what i would like to achieve it's to directly use the getter and write something like:

```
    let dic = NSDictionary()
    dic[.Key1]
```

So how can i use my custom enum directly on my NSDictionary getter method.

Comment: So why did you write it as `valueForKey` if that isn't what you wanted? If you wanted subscripting you should have written a `subscript` method, shouldn't you?

Comment: @LeoDabus i know that, but it doesn't was just an example to show what i want achieve.

Comment: @matt yes you are right, I wrote that just to be more clear and show an example. However if you know how to do it fell free to explain it to me.

Comment: Feel free to make at least a try on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want something like this

```
extension NSDictionary {
  enum DBKeys : String {
    case Key1 = "Key1", Key2 = "Key2", Key3 = "Key3"
  }

  subscript (key: DBKeys) -> AnyObject? {
    get {
      return self[key.rawValue]
    }
  }
}


let dic = NSDictionary(objects: ["Alpha", "Beta"], forKeys: ["Key1", "Key2"])
dic[.Key1] // "Alpha"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You don't even have to add an extension to `NSDictionary`:

```
enum DBKeys : String {
    case Key1 = "Key1", Key2 = "key2", Key3 = "key3"
}

var dic = [DBKeys : String]()

dic[.Key1] = "hello world"
println(dic[.Key1]!) // hello world
```